# Create/Delete TFSTATE file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I was wondering what would be the issue if I create a tfstate file for each Azure Devops pipeline using the git feature branch name then delete it afterwards?

This would mean that tfstate locking issue would become a non-issue for each individual development.

This is just a potential solution

Comment: Your question didn't make a lot of sense to me, but it sounds like you might want to look in to using terragrunt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to run a `terraform plan` on your PR/non-main-branches before you merge then apply your terraform plan.

If that's correct you can run add [`-lock=false`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#lock-false) to your plan command:

```
terraform plan -lock=false
```

Which would only run a terraform plan without locking the state. Note that this might be a dangerous operation since it may not reflect your actual infrastructure state.

The goal of a state file is to have a reflection of what you have in your infrastructure, so it would make sense to keep one state file and make it as a source of truth and avoid copying it for each feature branch